# How can I prevent Java from redirecting to download an update?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, java, internet-explorer, windows-server-2008

Each time I go to a page that uses Java, I am redirected to the Java download page because my version of Java is out of date. While I'd happily download the newest version of Java, I'm on a Windows 2008 R2 terminal server/Remote Desktop server and can't very well kick 20 people out of IE while I update.

Turns out this happens when Java squawks about needing an update and the user clicks the "Update" button. Henceforth, it will redirect to the Java download page regardless of the user's privileges.

How can I prevent redirection to the Java download page?

Comment: I thought Chrome just did a bar at the top of the window that you can click away - not redirect.

Comment: It's supposed to, but for me and several other users clicking the "Run away" button redirects to the Java download page.

Comment: Turns out this happens when Java squawks about needing an update and the user clicks the "Update" button. Henceforth, it will redirect to the Java download page regardless of the user's privileges.